# vba-Excel: Selenium.Start not work. Why?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, vba, web, selenium

I have installed the latest version of Selenium from this link: https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest
I have move the latest ChromeDriver in the SeleniumBasic Folder: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
I have enabled the "Selenium Type Library" on the "References".
The Chrome window opens and closes by itself after a few seconds:

```
Sub StartChrome()
    Dim Selenium As New ChromeDriver
    Selenium.Start , "https://www.google.it/"
End Sub
```

[image]

Why?

Microsoft Office 365 Home Premium Retail v16.0.9029.2167 (latest version) (Office 2016)
Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!! :-D

```
Option Explicit
Private Chrome As New ChromeDriver
Sub ChromeAutomation()
    Chrome.Start: Chrome.Get "https://www.google.it/"
End Sub
```